# How to change the duration of app-open ad?

Tags: flutter, admob, flutter-futurebuilder, google-mobile-ads

I am using Flutter, and trying to build an app using app open ad(by google admob) and Future Builder.
Because future builder takes long, I want to keep the ad displayed for longer than 5 seconds, or close the ad after future builder gets data.
I have already implemented both admob, and future builder.

[The relationship between openApp ad and FutureBuilder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dzlWL.png)

Could you teach me how to change the duration to show ad?

If you want more information to answer this, please let me know.
Thanks!

code:

```
    AppOpenAd? openAd;
Future<void> loadInitialAd()async{
  await AppOpenAd.load(
    adUnitId: AdHelper.startAppAdUnitId,
    request: const AdRequest(),
    adLoadCallback: AppOpenAdLoadCallback(
      onAdLoaded: (ad){
        print("Ad is loaded");
        openAd = ad;
        openAd!.show();
      },
      onAdFailedToLoad: (error){
        print("ad failed to load ${error}");
      }
    ), orientation: AppOpenAd.orientationPortrait
  );
}

void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await MobileAds.instance.initialize();
  await Firebase.initializeApp(
    options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
  );

  runApp(MyApp());
}

    class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return 
        return MaterialApp(
            home:MyHomePage());          
    );
  }
}
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {

}
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
       
        body: FutureBuilder<List<MonumentModel>>(
          future: MonumentModel.fetchMonument(),
          builder: (context, snapshot) {

return 
snapshot.hasData ? Container(child: Widget(snapshot!.data))
                  : SizedBox(child: Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator())),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without seeing the code it is difficult to help you, but did you check the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/admob/flutter/app-open)? Reading the docs, it seems that the ad is not automatically dismissed, which tells me that most likely your ad is dismissed by something else. Probably a navigation event that is used to show your loading screen.

Check the [`FullScreenContentCallback` declaration](https://developers.google.com/admob/flutter/app-open#:%7E:text=ad%2C%20register%20a-,FullScreenContentCallback,-for%20each%20ad) to see how the ad should be shown and dismissed.

Comment: Thank you very much for your kind comment even though I did not include my code.
I added basic code in my post.
The ad will be closed by tapping ">" button in the image. Problem is, users can close the ad by tapping ">" around only after 1 second... I want make it longer.
As far as I understand the document, it controls only the action when to load ads, not dismiss..?

Comment: Thanks for adding the code. As far as I know, it's not possible to intercept/modify the way ads work. What you may want to try is to move the logic for showing the ad until the future is complete (ensuring that the app is ready when the user dismisses the ad). Alternatively, you might have better luck with [Interstitial ads](https://developers.google.com/admob/flutter/interstitial), as I believe those can stay on screen for longer.

Comment: Thank you. I will try to use interstital ads instead..